# How to push Firestore data to ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, chart.js

I'm having a problem with plotting data to ChartJS from Firestore data. For some reason it only shows a single value on the bottom of the graph and random number on y-axis instead of date. I hope someone can help me. 
My firestore  : [firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn8EY.png)
 My chart : [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKqxJ.png)

Here's what I have so far.

```
    db.collection('Items').get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        var item= doc.data();

        var price= item.price;
        var date = item.date;

    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [date],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Items',
            data: [price],  
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        },
        // Container for pan options
        pan: {
            // Boolean to enable panning
            enabled: true,

            // Panning directions. 
            mode: 'x',

            speed: 1
        },

        // Container for zoom options
        zoom: {
            // enable zooming
            enabled: true,                      
            // Zooming directions. 
            mode: 'x',
            }
        }
    });
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `doc` in the `snapshot` you are doing `var myChart = new Chart()`, creating a new chart **each time**.

You should build your `data` and `labels` arrays in the `forEach` and then (**outside** the `forEach`) create a new chart and pass it the arrays.

Something like the following (not tested):

```
var labelsArray = [];
var dataArray = [];

db.collection('Items').get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        var item = doc.data();

        var price = item.price;
        dataArray.push(price);

        var date = item.date;
        labelsArray.push(date);
    });
});

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: {
    labels: labelsArray,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Items',
        data: dataArray ,  
    }]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
    },
    // Container for pan options
    pan: {
        // Boolean to enable panning
        enabled: true,

        // Panning directions. 
        mode: 'x',

        speed: 1
    },

    // Container for zoom options
    zoom: {
        // enable zooming
        enabled: true,                      
        // Zooming directions. 
        mode: 'x',
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, seems like there is a problem with my data for (dataArray) `price` that contains `$` symbol, it doesn't display the data. For the labelsArray, strangely the data only show on the graph when I resize my browser. Any ideas?

Comment: Solved the chart render on window resize. If I am not mistaken, the causes of chartJS rendering issue is because the chart is created in a hidden element `div`. Reference [CharJs render on window resize](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/17).